# limiting ANCOVA comparisons in R

Tags: r

So I have my data

```
 str(data1)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Genotype      : Factor w/ 2 levels "EXP","WT": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Stimulus       : Factor w/ 2 levels "2oo","o": 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ MI          : num  0.08 -0.13 0.08 -0.39 -0.29 -0.16 0.13 0.08 0.08 -0.31  ..
 ...
```

and I perform my anova

```
 aov.MI <- aov(MI ~ Genotype*Stimulus, data=data1)
```

But if I run a TukeyHSD I get all the possible combinations

```
    $`Genotype:Stimulus`
                  diff          lwr       upr     p adj
WT:2oo-EXP:2oo -0.08000000 -0.363226668 0.2032267 0.8031324    
EXP:o-EXP:2oo   0.29666667  0.013439999 0.5798933 0.0403984
WT:o-EXP:2oo    0.21000000 -0.073226668 0.4932267 0.1599365
EXP:o-WT:2oo    0.37666667  0.093439999 0.6598933 0.0118146
WT:o-WT:2oo     0.29000000  0.006773332 0.5732267 0.0448986
WT:o-EXP:o     -0.08666667 -0.369893335 0.1965600 0.7644713
```

How can I set the TukeyHSD, or do any other appropriate post-analysis only to have the

WT:2oo-EXP:2oo
EXP:o-EXP:2oo
WT:o-EXP:2oo
WT:o-EXP:o

comparisons and ignore the ones which do not share a common factor i.e. WT:2oo-EXP:o and WT:o-EXP:2oo? Can I use the 'which' option in TukeyHSD to be so specific? Is there an easier way to do it?

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Look at `glht` in the `multcomp` package. There you can test specific coefficients against each other (or against some specified value)